# R: how to shorten a value to just one number inside the value

Tags: r, replace

| Chromosome_name | Start Position |
| --- | --- |
| CHR_HSCHR7_2_CTG6 | 142857940 |
| CHR_HSCHR19LRC_PGF2_CTG3_1 | 54316049 |

I have just started to use R.
I have a data frame of chromosome names but I just want to replace the long names with the number of the chromosome.
i.e CHR_HSCHR19LRC_PGF2_CTG3_1 would be "19"
I need to replace the long name with the number just after the characters "HRCHR"
How would I do this?

I tried the method of manually entry the replacement value:
`gsub(".*HSCHR19", "19", dataframe)`

But this takes far too long for a list of >100 values. I would like to find a way to do this automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```r
sub('^.*CHR(\\d+).*$', '\\1', Chromosome_name)
#> [1] "7"  "19"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another potential option is a [look-behind regex](https://debuggingdata.com/post/r/regular-expressions-look-arounds/), e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "Chromosome_name    Start_Position
CHR_HSCHR7_2_CTG6   142857940
CHR_HSCHR19LRC_PGF2_CTG3_1  54316049", header = TRUE)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(Chromosome_name = str_extract(Chromosome_name, "(?<=HSCHR)\\d+"))

df2
#>   Chromosome_name Start_Position
#> 1               7      142857940
#> 2              19       54316049
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks very much guys they both work really well but the second one ended up removing the chromosome names that were already numbers (I should have said I have a mix of character strings and numbers). I finally went with a combination of the two methods above and it worked!

df2<- df %>% mutate(chromosome_name=sub('^.*CHR(\\d+).*$', '\\1', chromosome_name))